# Login with Facebook creates different user

Tags: bug, login, ios-app, facebook, multiple-accounts

I downloaded the Stack Exchange app and decided to log in with Facebook. When I logged in, I realised the app had created a different user account than the one I normally log on to the site with (also using Facebook).

My other account is under the username KerrM. Perhaps worth noting is that the first time I downloaded (v1.0), I tried to log in with Facebook, but I kept getting an error – didn't record it, but it didn't let me log in. Because of this I decided to register with Facebook (always from within the app). That worked, but I didn't see any user information displayed (don't know if v1.0 showed the user logged in or not; perhaps it didn't).

Once the updated version was available, I uninstalled v1.0 and installed the new one – then I tried logging in with Facebook, and I was greeted by this username.

Comment: Well without knowing both the accounts we can't really diagnose it. Your current account does not have a Facebook login associated with it.

Comment: Hey. Sorry I should have thought of that - the other account's username is KerrM. Let me update the question with more information.

Comment: This account has an email address recorded under "Other" (you can see it by clicking "my logins" on your profile). The only thing I can think of would be that the app is incorrectly reporting the email address it fetches from your Facebook profile as the OpenID source itself.

Comment: Can I see the email within the app? On the website if I click login with Facebook I get logged in as KerrM

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to view your logins from the app.